# Как реализовать автоматическое сообщение Telegram bota

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать автоматическое сообщение Telegram bota при определенном критерии.
Что сделано:

- создается SQL запрос в БД по текущей температуре датчика
- по команде /temp - бот выводит тек. температуру

Что необходимо:

- в питоне создать расписание (например каждые 30 минут), по которому происходит запрос SQL, и если температура например превышает порог в 30 градусов - выводится сообщение в ТГ боте.

Кто сталкивался, подскажите механизм осуществления данной задачи!

Мои попытки заставить выводить сообщение привет, не увенчались успехом:

```py
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, parse_mode=None) #токен в отдельном файле

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')

def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(start)
    
    Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
TypeError: start1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Почему грешит на аргумент не понимаю...

Comment: В приведенном коде - нет указанной ошибки, покажите тот код который вызывает эту ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
# зачем ты вообще пишешь parse_mode=None? Он же такой по-умолчанию
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, parse_mode=None) #токен в отдельном файле

def sender():
    # список с юзер айди который ты должен получить из бд
    user_ids = []
    for id in user_ids:
        try:
            bot.send_message(id, 'Привет')
        except Exception:
            pass        

def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(sender)
    
    Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```